# Movie Database Queries

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database

I need your help with my movie quiz app which ask user a question and come up with 4 answers (1 right and 3 wrong). I have to find queries for app but it's doesn't seem to work for me.

Here is the schema for tables -

table one (`movies`) has 4 values - id (primary key), title (title of the movie), year (year of release), director (director of the movie)

table two (`stars`) has 3 values - id (primary key), first_name, last_name

table three (`stars_in_movies`) has 2 values - movie_id, star_id (movie_id and star_id both are foreign keys here

Now, for the questions:

I have to come up with queries for the following questions and these are queries I came up with.

1. Which star was in movie x?

   ```
   select first_name,last_name
     from stars_in_movies inner join stars
    where movie_id=%s and star_id=id;
   ```

   (This works fine)
2. Who directed the star x?

   ```
   select director
     from movies inner join stars_in_movies
    where star_id=%s and movie_id = id;
   ```

   (This doesn't seem to be working)
3. Which star appears in both movies x and y?

   ```
   select first_name,last_name
     from stars_in_movies inner join stars
    where (movie_id=%s and movie_id=%y) and star_id=id;
   ```

   (This doesn't seem to be working either)
4. Which star did not appear in the same movie as star x?

   (I don't know how to approach this query but I am thinking about making a helper function to pick a random movie with at least 3 stars in it, then use 1 star in the question, and the other two as wrong answers. Then just find another random star that hasn't been in a movie with the first star. but I don't know how to write code for it)

Comment: Please edit your question and put code in code blocks. This is also not about both SQL-server AND MySQL, which is it?

Comment: can you rephrase your question 4?

Comment: @arunmoezhi - Sure, its same as "Which star has not been in a movie with star X?"

Comment: please give an example

Comment: hmm, ok .. for example .. let just sat "star1" and "star2" has never worked together. so, when I ask question -- 
which star has not worked with "star2" ? - answer should be "star1" .. 
I hope that made sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which star did not appear in the same movie as star x?

```
select first_name --All stars who have not acted with star X
from stars
where star_id not in
(
    select star_id --All stars who have acted with star X
    from stars_in_movies
    where movie_id in
    (
        select movie_id     --All movies in which star X has acted
        from stars_in_movies
        where star_id = "X"
    )
)
```

--Which star appears in both movies x and y?

```
select A.first_name
from stars A,
(
select star_id
from stars_in_movies
where movie_id = "X"
)B,
(   
select star_id
from stars_in_movies
where movie_id = "Y"
)C
where A.star_id = B.star_id
AND B.star_id = C.star_id
```

who directed the star X?

```
select director -- directors who have worked with star X
from movies
where movie_id in
(
    select movie_id  --All movies in which star X has acted
    from stars_in_movies
    where star_id = "X"
)
```

Comment: could you please take a look at question 2 and 3 queries? Those queries doesn't seems to be working.

Comment: Thank you very much :) Appreciate it much.